# How do I link Armadillo with nvblas on windows

Tags: c++, armadillo, mlpack, nvblas

So I want to use mlpack (https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack) with nvblas.
Now mlpack uses armadillo.

I been looking online for a guide that will explain to me how to setup armadillo and mlpack with nvblas and I can't find one (especially one that explains it on windows)

Currently I'm using OpenBLAS, VS17 and CMake
Using the following arguments with CMake
Armadillo:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DBLAS_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/mlpack/mlpack/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/native/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" -DLAPACK_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/mlpack/mlpack/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/native/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" -DCMAKE_PREFIX:FILEPATH="C:/mlpack/armadillo" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```

mlpack:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DBLAS_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/mlpack/mlpack/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/native/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" -DLAPACK_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/mlpack/mlpack/packages/OpenBLAS.0.2.14.1/lib/native/lib/x64/libopenblas.dll.a" -DARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR="C:/mlpack/armadillo/include" -DARMADILLO_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/mlpack/armadillo/build/Debug/armadillo.lib" -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR:PATH="C:/boost/boost_1_66_0/" -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR:PATH="C:/boost/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.1" -DDEBUG=OFF -DPROFILE=OFF ..
```

Comment: So, what is your problem? P.S. `libopenblas.dll.a` looks like it's a non windows library. Windows libraries usually use .lib or .dll extensions.

Comment: The problem is how to use nvblas instead of openblas (the openblas one works)